# PHP Fatal error: Failure in wincache (windows azure)

Tags: php, codeigniter, azure

I have codeigniter framework in my project. My website is running on windows azure platform. Sometimes it's giving me this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Failure in Wincache[6484] free_memory: Block 0x41d56d8 not in use
>    in D:\home\site\wwwroot\system\libraries\Log.php on line 44

I tried to change php.ini file by changing value of memory:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
```

But, then after I checked `memory_get_peak_usage();` then I found that application is not even using more than `1MB`. I don't know what's going on here. I am getting blank page and website gets down when this happens.

Please, ask me if you need more information or code.

**Log.php:**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $config =& get_config();

    $this->_log_path = ($config['log_path'] != '') ? $config['log_path'] : APPPATH.'logs/';

    if ( ! is_dir($this->_log_path) OR ! is_really_writable($this->_log_path)) // This is line 44.
    {
        $this->_enabled = FALSE;
    }

    if (is_numeric($config['log_threshold']))
    {
        $this->_threshold = $config['log_threshold'];
    }

    if ($config['log_date_format'] != '')
    {
        $this->_date_fmt = $config['log_date_format'];
    }
}
```

log.php file is default codeigniter file.

**FINAL SOLUTION:**

I have updated my `php.ini` file with this:

```
wincache.fcenabled=0
wincache.ocenabled=0
wincache.ucenabled=0
wincache.reroute_enabled = 0
wincache.srwlocks = 0
```

Comment: What web server are you using, Apache, IIS, other? What's on line 44 of the D:\home\site\wwwroot\system\libraries\Log.php file?

Comment: This indicates that WinCache was trying to double-free a block of memory in the cross-process shared memory segment.

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro: I am using windows azure. And I have updated my question.

Comment: compelled http://i.imgur.com/XI5IsGn.png

Comment: You mentioned the fatal error occures sometimes. Did you figured out possible actions that may cause it yet? Like requesting a specific page.

Answer (score 3):

It's an issue with IIS or WinCache on Windows Server. You can follow [official thread](http://forums.iis.net/t/1210919.aspx?HTTP%20500%20errors%20and%20Wincache%20crashes%20Request%20for%20Info) on a iis forum.
Just to be sure, check following options in your php.ini:

```
wincache.reroute_enabled = 0
wincache.srwlocks = 0
```

Also update wincache to a latest version.

Comment: I have updated php.ini file. Now, I need to wait for next failure. Because it happens only sometimes. Previously it wan't like that. Can you please explain what is this error and what could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: @RonakPatel After the update to 1.3.7 the reroute function Feature was enabled. It made an error in a file operation that lead to the deathlock. So you logger stops somethimes and clients get a 500 http error.

Comment: I am about version of php_wincache.dll

Answer (score 0):

The specific WinCache error message has been removed as of WinCache 1.3.7.5, which was pushed out in a recent Azure Web Services update.

As for the meaning of the error message: While attempting to free a block of memory in a cross-process shared memory segment, WinCache detected that the block had already been freed.  The message indicates that WinCache detected the problem, and **avoided** corrupting memory.  The message should really be a Warning level message.  Further, the executing request should run to completion, and a response should be returned to the customer.

Prior to WinCache 1.3.7.4, WinCache did **not** detect this scenario, and would wind up corrupting memory, which would eventually lead to an AV.  So, the error message actually indicates that WinCache just saved you from crashing, and you're welcome!

Comment: Yeah. I just get notification on that. :)